# Python parsing code with new line character in them using ast

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a string representation of the code, like the example given below

```
code='''
print('\n')
print('hello world')
'''
import ast
ast.parse(code)
```

Throws an error

```
print(" 
       ^
 SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

The new line character seems to be pushing the single quote to the next line before parse.Escaping '\n' solves the issue, but this would require looping through each line in the string. Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What seems to be happening is your 'code' is being interpreted by python before it can be parsed by ast. You can pass it as a raw string by putting an 'r' before the string and it seems to work;

```
code=r'''
print('\n')
print('hello world')
'''

import ast
ast.parse(code)
```